# How to send and get data between two view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two view controller in storyboard.
VC1 has three buttons and VC2 has a image view.

When click button A in VC1, then VC2 show image of A.
When click button B in VC1, then VC2 show image of B.

How VC2 can know which button was clicked in VC1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple!!!

1) in VC2 create NSString property in .h file and then synthesize that in .m file "NSStringObjofVC2"
2) import VC2 in VC1 .h file #import "VC2"
and create object like this

VC2 *vc2Obj;

3) in viewdidload method

vc2Obj = [[VC2 alloc] init];

4) on each button click add this

vc2Obj.NSStringObjofVC2 = @"differentImageNameforAll3Buttons.png";

last to use the image in VC2

simply use NSStringObjofVC2 in UIImage as filename

Comment: Thanks for your guide line. I value your help. It support me to make easier and faster. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a delegate in VC2 to send info back to the original VC.
Google "objective-c delegate" and do some reading on the model-view-controller paradigm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It help me to save my time of developing apps.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Segue:

1. Add a Navigation Controller : select VC1, then Editor> Embedded In> Navigation Controller
2. Give a segue Connection from Button A to VC2, from Button B to VC2, from Button A to VC2l
3. Enter the segue identifier SegueA, SegueB, SegueC respectively.
4. Write the following Method in VC1:

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

```
ImageViewController *vc2=(ImageViewController*)[ segue destinationViewController];

if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SegueA"]){

vc2.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];

}else
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SegueB"]){

        vc2.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];

}else
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SegueC"]){

vc2.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"c.png"];

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your advice and help. I'm a beginner for iOS. I don't know a lot of iOS. Your help support for my learning. Thanks again.